# Is there any way in Xamarin Forms to change the background color of a dialog box?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's what my dialog box looks like with a dark theme.

[image]

Does anyone know of a way that the colors could be changed in a Xamarin Forms app so that the dialog displays with white text on a dark background?

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Option 1**

You could change it in specific platforms by using **DependencyService**

#### in forms

create the interface

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace xxx
{
    public interface IPopUp
    {
        void Popup(string title, string message,Color titleColor,Color messageColor, EventHandler handler);
    }
}
```

#### in iOS

```
using System;


using System.Text;
using xxx.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using xxx;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PopupImplemention))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class PopupImplemention : IPopUp
    {
        public void Popup(string title, string message, Color titleColor, Color messageColor, EventHandler handler)
        {
            UIAlertController alertController = UIAlertController.Create(title,message,UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

           
            var firstAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
            {
                ForegroundColor =titleColor.ToUIColor(),
               
            };

            var secondAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
            {
                ForegroundColor =messageColor.ToUIColor(),
               
            };

            alertController.SetValueForKey(new NSAttributedString(title, firstAttributes), new NSString("attributedTitle"));
            alertController.SetValueForKey(new NSAttributedString(message, secondAttributes), new NSString("attributedMessage"));

            UIAlertAction cancelAction = UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel",UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel,null);
            UIAlertAction okAction = UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default,(sender)=> { handler?.Invoke(sender, new EventArgs()) ; });

            alertController.AddAction(cancelAction);
            alertController.AddAction(okAction);

            var currentViewController = topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().RootViewController);
            currentViewController.PresentViewController(alertController,true,null);
        }



        UIViewController topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIViewController rootViewController)
        {
            if (rootViewController is UITabBarController)
            {
                UITabBarController tabBarController = (UITabBarController)rootViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(tabBarController.SelectedViewController);
            }
            else if (rootViewController is UINavigationController)
            {
                UINavigationController navigationController = (UINavigationController)rootViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(navigationController.VisibleViewController);
            }
            else if (rootViewController.PresentedViewController != null)
            {
                UIViewController presentedViewController = rootViewController.PresentedViewController;
                return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(presentedViewController);
            }
            else
            {
                return rootViewController;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

#### in Android

in MainActivity

```
public static MainActivity Intance;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
  ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Intance = this;
           
  Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
  global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            
  LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;
using Android;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Text;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PopupImplemention))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class PopupImplemention : IPopUp
    {
        public void Popup(string title, string message, Color titleColor, Color messageColor, EventHandler handler)
        {
            
            // because html.string could not support format string , so you need to set the color directly in the string with a static value

            Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.Intance);
            alert.SetTitle(Html.FromHtml(string.Format("<font color='#ff0000'>{0}</font>" ,title),FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy));
            alert.SetMessage(Html.FromHtml(string.Format("<font color='#00ff00'>{0}</font>", message), FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy));

            alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {
                handler?.Invoke(senderAlert, args);
            });

            alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (senderAlert, args) =>
            {

            });


            Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog dialog = alert.Create();
            dialog.Show();

       
        }
    }
}
```

And call it in forms

```
 DependencyService.Get<IPopUp>().Popup("Title","xxxxxxxxxxxx",Color.Red,Color.Blue,(sen,args)=> { 
            
       // handle the logic when  clikc the OK button   
            
});
```

### Option 2

You could use the plugin **[Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)** ,which allows to open Xamarin.Forms pages as a popup that can be shared across iOS, Android and UWP . And you can customize it as you want .

Comment: Hello,  I just tried out your solution for iOS so far but I am getting a null reference exception in the iOS custom renderer.  I put the details into the question.  Do you have any idea what might be wrong?  Note that I am using Xamarin Shell and the latest 4.4 version.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the screen shot ,you could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Hello Lucas, I used exactly your code with the DependencyService.  Sorry I was not clear that the problem was coming up with your code.

Comment: It works fine on my side ， so can you share your sample？

Comment: Hi Lucas, my sample is an application of over 200 files and a database.  I will need some time to come up with a small sample. It would appear to be failing at this point: SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow() so I am not sure if the debug output I showed helps or not.  What's it like in your code (which is identical to mine) if you debug at that point?

Comment: Did you set the mainpage as a navigation page?

Comment: I am using Xamarin Shell so it's not a navigation page. MainPage = new AppShell();

Comment: Try to create a new project and test my solution firstly or you could test the android party firstly

Comment: Tried in Xamarins project and it worked so I will try to compare the differences.  Will update tomorrow and/or accept answer if all is okay.